# Soap Webservice Response validation using citrus framework

Tags: citrus-framework

I am trying to validate the payload response came from the server,

```
soap()
  .server(todoServer)
  .send()
  .payload(new ClassPathResource("templates/getTodoListResponse.xml"));
```

Is there a way todo a field level validation like below using SoapActionBuilder,

```
http()
    .client(todoClient)
    .receive()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .validate("/t:todo/t:id", "${todoId}")
    .validate("/t:todo/t:title", "${todoName}")
    .validate("/t:todo/t:description", "${todoDescription}")
    .validate("/t:todo/t:done", "false");
```

Answer (score 0):

The SoapActionBuilder is also able to use XPath element validation.

```
soap()
    .client(todoClient)
    .receive()
    .validate("/t:todo/t:id", "${todoId}")
    .validate("/t:todo/t:title", "${todoName}")
    .validate("/t:todo/t:description", "${todoDescription}")
    .validate("/t:todo/t:done", "false");
```

Notice that the SOAP envelope is automatically handled in the Citrus client. So your XPath expression is able to use the payload root element as root base path for the expression. You can also tell Citrus to *not automatically* handle the SOAP envelope. Then your XPath expression need to use the `SOAP-ENV:Envelope` as root element.